# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isEditMode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to convert an AngularJS app to Vue JS. However, I keep getting js errors like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isEditMode' of undefined".

What I'm trying to do here is make the page editable when a vuetify icon is clicked which in turn calls a function and displays some other icons. The code I currently have is as follows:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        saveView: false,
        isPageEdit: false,
        saveFailed: false,
        isPageLocked: false,
        editFailed: false,
        timerMessage: false,
        boundData:
            {
                sections: {
                    isEditMode: null
                }
            }
    },

    methods:
        {
            setedit: function (isEditMode, sectionId) {
                this.boundData.sections[sectionId].isEditMode = isEditMode;
                validation(sectionId);
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make sections an array of objects first. then you can access your property like that

so something like this

```
sections: [
  {isEditMode: null},
  {isEditMode: true},
]
```

or if you'd like to keep the current data structure you have then you can directly access isEditMode like that this.boundData.sections.isEditMode

Comment: Thanks but can you please tell how exactly the data structure can be modified in this case, keeping the sections[] intact?

Comment: writing sections[] like that makes it an array. so vueJs will always look for a sections property of type array and as you may have expected it won't find it and will always return that undefined error to you. so as I said you have to either make sections[] an array of objects  so you can access it with this line 'this.boundData.sections[sectionId].isEditMode' or keep it as it is and access it like that 'this.boundData.sections.isEditMode'

Comment: I understand that but i need help regarding the exact syntax for that in terms of the code...

Comment: you're asking vue to read a certain array that doesn't exist! so as far as I know it can't be done with the same exact snytax. you will have to change something

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure doesn't match how you're trying to index it. You have defined

```
`boundData.sections.isEditMode`
```

and you are trying to reference

```
`boundData.sections[sectionId].isEditMode`
```